# Hashable tuple-like collections in TypeScript

Tags: dictionary, typescript, hash, ecmascript-6

I'm writing a (toy) hash-and-cache decorator in TypeScript and can't find a good means of creating a solid generic one.

The code I have so far is

```
function cache
  (target: Object,
  propertyKey: string,
  // Likely we can do better than <any> here -- <Function<any>> maybe?
  descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>) 
{
  let cacheMap = new Map();
  let wrappedFn = descriptor.value;

  descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
    if (cacheMap.has(args)) {
        console.log("Short-circuiting with result: " + cacheMap.get(args));
        return cacheMap.get(args);
    }
    let result = wrappedFn.apply(this, args);
    cacheMap.set(args, result);
    console.log("cacheMap %o", cacheMap);
    return result;
  }

  return descriptor;
}
```

Naturally this fails, since `args` is not a tuple but a list, which is mutable[1]. So each input, even if it's the same over and over, gets its own list/array in its own memory location with its own hash value, wherever that comes from.

I haven't found a Tuple type in TypeScript (or JS) yet -- is there one? Is there another workaround for this sort of problem?

1. Shouldn't this be an error? `Map<T, U>` should constrain `T` to implementing `IHashable` or something, right? That's the point of types -- to raise this issue before it takes a bunch of time out of your life.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't add new runtime functionality or libraries -- probably not the right title. Any solution would involve a vanilla-JS library or solution.

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh thanks. I'll take a look.

Answer (score -1):

> Shouldn't this be an error? `Map<T, U>` should constrain T to implementing IHashable or something, right?

No. Object identity is a real and well-defined thing in JavaScript; TypeScript doesn't attempt to force you to pretend it doesn't exist.

If the ECMAScript committee thought it was appropriate to enforce non-object-identity-based keying in maps, they could have restricted `Map` keys, but they didn't.